# Let x be real. Show that, for any ϵ>0, there exist two rationals such that q<x<q′ and |q−q′|<ϵ

Tags: real-analysis

My main problem with this question is choosing epsilon, I don't know how to choose it, could someone help me out please?  If you want to help me with the whole problem go ahead, but my main struggle is the second part.

I'm new with writing proofs like this, this is my first analysis class so try to be clear please.  Thanks I appreciate all the help and advice in advance.

Comment: In this problem you must consider that $\varepsilon$ is any arbitrarily small real number, and then show the existence of $q,q'$. That is, you're not choosing epsilon, but instead are given it.

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume you already know the denseness of rationals. With that, there is a rational $q$ in $(x-\epsilon/2,x)$ and there is another rational $q'$ in $(x,x+\epsilon/2)$. You can check that $q$ and $q'$ satisfy your requirements.